# Keep getting this error: Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: express, model-view-controller, routes, controllers

I am trying to set up a react express application with mongo db as the database. I am in the preliminary stages and keep coming across this error:

```
 Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
// const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


//db  and name is auth

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auth', {
    useMongoClient: true,
    /* other options */
  });
// app setup

//server setup

const port = process.env.Port || 4000
// const server = http.createServer(app);
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Sever listening on ${port}`)

const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth_routes');
app.use('/',authRoutes);
```

my routes are right here. I am just testing to see if there is a correct connection.

```
const authController = '../controllers/auth_controller';
const express = require('express');
const authRoutes = express.Router();


    authRoutes.post('/',authController.signup)



module.exports = authRoutes;
```

my controller is listed below:

```
const authController = {};

authController.signup = function(req,res,next) {
    console.log('here');
    res.json({
        user: "doesnt matter",
        data: 'Put a user profile on this route'
      });
}

module.exports = authController;
```

not sure if mongo is the problem since it is my first time using it, but my connection to the database works robo 3t to check whats in the database and the user schema is there. if i comment out that one route in the routes page, the errors go away.

Comment: Since this is a simple error because you just forgot to import something, feel free to delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is here:

```
const authController = '../controllers/auth_controller';

authRoutes.post('/',authController.signup)
```

Note that `authController` is just a string. I'm guessing you intended:

```
const authController = require('../controllers/auth_controller');
```

Comment: wow..... what a stupid mistake smh lol I have been coding for so many hours. appreciate the point out! I didn't even notice i forgot the require.